# JMETER Rampup for 20users and 600 ysers

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, neoload

Can someone please help me with the best Ramp up time for 20 users as well as 600 users.

I have given Users: 20, Rampup: 60 sec , which is leading to Reason for socket exception in Client-Server Application

I have given Users: 20, Rampup: 60 sec , which is leading to Reason for socket exception in Client-Server Application

Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException/Non HTTP response message: Socket closed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best ramp-up time", there is only a recommendation to increase the load gradually so you would be able to correlate increasing load with other metrics like response time, throughput, number of errors, etc.

If you need a quote with it comes to suggested ramp-up period you can stick to official [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) which states:

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> **Start with Ramp-up = number of threads** and adjust up or down as needed.

"Socket exception" is too broad term, there could be multiple reasons behind it and therefore multiple solutions. If it doesn't happen for 1-2 users and happens for 20 - most probably your application gets overloaded somehow and cannot process that many requests. You can take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
and/or add the next line to [system.properties file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization):

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

and next time you run your test you will see a lot of debugging information in the [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))

More information:

- [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)
- [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed)

Comment: I have been giving Ramup : 480 seconds for 20 users , Duration to hold the window for 1200000ms ( 20 min ). Can the ramup be enough for 20 users.

Comment: If now I want to test for 600 users rampup is going for 4hrs. Will thjat be a good ram,up to execute ?